# Change default date format of the asp sql database ( the one storing the values)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a gridview and SqlDatasource.
I have a column called Date VMS which is type Date.
I've noticed that the format for adding a date won't allow adding a date like: 30/02/2012. ( DD/MM/YYYY)

I have an Excel sheet from which I'm copying the rows and I'm adding them in the table.

[image]

The format of the date in the Excel is: `DD/MM/YYYY`, so as we can see when I'm pasting the value in the table, the dates which are not format MM.DD.YYYY are not added.

- -And some of them : for example 7/12/2012, the program assimilate them as MM/DD/YYY.

I've also added the date manually in the second cell of the first row and the database doesn't allow that format.

Is there any way to change the date format so I can add dd.mm.yyyy?

Comment: You can very easily create a new column in excel with format to match sql server.

Comment: I asked for how to change the format in the data table not changing the exel format please follow my question

Comment: SQL stores date/time values in binary form. The *format* of how the value is displayed is not controlled by SQL, but by the application that extracts the data and presents it to the user.

Comment: So , what shall I to change this?

Comment: @Jax that's why I posted a comment and not an answer. I don't think you can specify format for date in a table. What I was trying to suggest was that, if all you are trying to do is get your copy/paste working, maybe you can change your excel file create a new column linked to the original date column but formatted to match what sql server expects.

Comment: @Jax - The problem you have Jax is that Date field in your excel document is not in a valid date format. I have never see a date written with periods instead of a backslash. You are going to need to read in the excel sheet's date value, and write it back out in a valid date format, excel does not understand dd/mm/yyyy based on my quick and dirty testing.  I have to downvote this for being dismissive.

Comment: I did that because the database is auto replacing the '.' with '/' and because I set globalization to RO and the date format set by the globalization is with periods .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only 2 solution to your problem. The first and less complicated is the do like Bala suggest, add a new column with the right format for SQL Server.

The other solution is to go in the "Regional and Language" option the control panel and change the Date format in the Advance Setting. SQL Server use those setting to validate and display Date value. The problem with using such unusual date format might cause problem to other software.

Answer (score 0):

A standard way of copying data from excel into SQL Server (assumimg you are using SQL Server) is to use SQL Server's Intregration Services (formerly Data Transformation Services).  There, you can actually map your date columns and it will handle everything for you.

Below is a tutorial using SQL Server 2005, but is the same for more recent versions of SQL Server.

Tutorial: [How to import an Excel file into SQL Server 2005 using Integration Services](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-to-import-an-excel-file-into-sql-server-2005-using-integration-services/205)